# Insert Large Blob with Java Cassandra Driver

Tags: java, cassandra, blob

I need to insert about 8Mb of data into a Cassandra blob column.  I get a BufferOverflowException when I try to create the ByteBuffer object with the the byte data before sending it to Cassandra.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that if I create a byte array first and then "wrap" it in a ByteBuffer, I just have to make sure the JVM has enough memory.
The Cassandra driver accepts it fine.

Comment: It's not really a solution, just imagine that you need to write a blob sized to 132Gb. Also look here: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.9/faq/#can-i-store-large-blobs-in-cassandra